# Use PowerShell to create a OneDrive Shortcut for a SharePoint folder?

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive

Viewing a SharePoint folder, there is a button for "Add Shortcut to OneDrive". Clicking that creates a OneDrive Shortcut, indicated by a folder icon with a blue link decoration on it, in OneDrive MyFiles.

If I have a web link for a SharePoint folder, is there a way to programmatically create a OneDrive Shortcut from the link?

A limitation is that I cannot create an Azure AD app.  I'm currently using the following to leverage the current user credentials for all calls;

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $odSiteUrl -UseWebLogin -WarningAction Ignore
```

GH CoPilot suggests this code, which does not work at all:

```
Add-PnPFile -Folder $odFolderUrl -SourceUrl $spFolderUrl -Values @{LinkingUrl=$spFolderUrl; LinkingDisplayName=$odShortcutName} -ShortcutUrl

`$odFolderUrl` is the OneDrive folder I want to create the link in
`$spFolderUrl` is the Sharepoint folder I want to link to
`$odShortcutName` is name I want the shortcut folder to have
```

Comment: CoPilot suggested you to create a simple shortcut file and store it in a folder within SharePoint. Mayby this module is what you are looking for: https://github.com/derpenstiltskin/onedriveshortcuts

Comment: @Christoffer - Thanks for the suggestion. `onedriveshortcuts` requires that "To use this module you need to create an Azure AD application."  Unfortunately, that's a stone cold dead non-starter for my organization.  I'm using `Connect-PnPOnline -Url $odSiteUrl -UseWebLogin` to use the logged in user's credentials for all calls.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/derpenstiltskin/onedriveshortcuts

Can you try the below script and see what errors you get?
Replace `$spSiteUrl`, `$domain`, `$spFolder.Name`, `$odFolderUrl`, and `$spFolderUrl` with your actual values.

```
# Connect to SharePoint Online using the current user's credentials
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $spSiteUrl -UseWebLogin -WarningAction Ignore

# Get the current connection context
$spConnection = Get-PnPConnection

# Check if the connection is null
if ($null -eq $spConnection) {
    Write-Output "Not connected."
} else {
    Write-Output "Connected to $($spConnection.Url)."
}

# Define the target OneDrive folder URL based on current user's name
$username = [Environment]::USERNAME
$username = $username -replace '\.', '_'
$odSiteUrl = "https://$domain-my.sharepoint.com/personal/" + $username + "_my-company_com"

# Connect to SharePoint Online using the current user's credentials
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $odSiteUrl -UseWebLogin -WarningAction Ignore

# Get the current connection context
$odConnection = Get-PnPConnection

# Check if the connection is null
if ($null -eq $odConnection) {
    Write-Output "Not connected."
} else {
    Write-Output "Connected to $($odConnection.Url)."
}

# Create a OneDrive shortcut to the SharePoint folder
$odShortcutName = "Shortcut to $spFolder.Name"
Add-PnPFile -Folder $odFolderUrl -SourceUrl $spFolderUrl -Values @{LinkingUrl=$spFolderUrl; LinkingDisplayName=$odShortcutName} -ShortcutUrl

# Disconnect
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```